# How to modify and XML on the fly?

Tags: node.js, xml

I am reading a XML file and send it to a REST API. However before sending it I would like to modify some values.

This is how I send the data:

```
data = await readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, file), 'utf8');
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Length': data.length,
    },
};
result = await axios.post(
    'https://someRestapi.com/',
    data, config,
);
```

And I want to change the name Simon to Zimon in the author name for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document schemaVersion="12" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Author>
    <Name>
        <First>Simon</First>
        <Second>SomeName</Second>
    </Name>
 </Author>
</Document>
```

Is there an easy solution to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to do something similar recently and ended up using [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser). Applied to your case, you could do:

```
const xmlString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document schemaVersion="12" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Author>
    <Name>
        <First>Simon</First>
        <Second>SomeName</Second>
    </Name>
 </Author>
</Document>`;

const xmlToJsonParser = require('fast-xml-parser');
const J2xParser = require("fast-xml-parser").j2xParser;

const tObj = xmlToJsonParser.getTraversalObj(xmlString,{ignoreAttributes :false});
const jsonObj = xmlToJsonParser.convertToJson(tObj,{ignoreAttributes :false});

jsonObj.Document.Author.Name.First = "Zimon";

let result = new J2xParser({format:true, ignoreAttributes :false}).parse(jsonObj);
result = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n${result}`;
console.log(result);
```

This will print:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document schemaVersion="12" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Author>
    <Name>
      <First>Zimon</First>
      <Second>SomeName</Second>
    </Name>
  </Author>
</Document>
```

Comment: I was hoping that there is an easier solution :) but this absolutely works